# use multiple key in tidyr::gather

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

I used to use `reshape2::melt` to perform the following, since I want to learn `tidyr`, I wonder how this can be done in `tidyr::gather`:

```
iris %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(country=rep(LETTERS[1:3],ceiling(n()/3))[1:n()]) %>%
  reshape2::melt(.,id.var=c('country','Species'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
iris %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(country=rep(LETTERS[1:3],ceiling(n()/3))[1:n()]) %>%
  gather(., key = variable , value = value, -Species,-country)
```

This will gather all columns but Species and country (specified by the minus signs) and call the column containing the variable names 'variable' (the `key`) and the entry 'value' (the `value`).